# Applying decorator to view - url not being found by reverse

Tags: python, django, decorator, python-decorators

I am using `django 1.7` and the module `django-role-permissions`.

In my `login/urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^$', views.login),
   url(r'^logout$', views.logout),
   url(r'^create_user$', views.create_user),
)
```

and in `login/views.py`:

```
@has_role_decorator('EbagManager')
def create_user(request):
    return HttpResponse('OK')
```

I've got in one in my templates link to `create_user`: `<a href="{% url 'login.views.create_user' %}">Create User</a>`

Then I've got Django Exception:

```
NoReverseMatch at /core/index
Reverse for 'login.views.create_user' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

However when I remove `@has_role_decorator('EbagManager')` there is no problem with that url and successfully loaded it. What is going on?
This is the code of the decorator:

```
def has_role_decorator(role):
    def request_decorator(dispatch):
        def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            user = request.user
            if user.is_authenticated():
                if has_role(user, role):
                    return dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

            raise PermissionDenied
        return wrapper
    return request_decorator
```

and it seems perfectly fine to me. Why does this decorator break `reverse`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to copy across the name of the wrapped function (referenced by `dispatch`) to your `wrapper` function. This is easiest done with the [`@functools.wraps()` decorator factory](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps):

```
from functools import wraps

def has_role_decorator(role):
    def request_decorator(dispatch):
        @wraps(dispatch)
        def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            user = request.user
            if user.is_authenticated():
                if has_role(user, role):
                    return dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

            raise PermissionDenied
        return wrapper
    return request_decorator
```

Without using `@functools.wraps()`, `create_user.__name__` is set to `'wrapper'`, and the `create_user.__module__` attribute would name the module where you defined the decorator, meaning that to reverse the view you'd have to use `decorator_module.wrapper` as the lookup. Any view using the decorator would be registered under that name however.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this without changing the decorator by giving your URL a specific `name` attribute, and use that in reverse:

```
url(r'^create_user$', views.create_user, name='create_user'),
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - but after reading the other answer I am very curious why this works - how does `reserve` find `views.create_user`?